# Can I check the absolute continuity of two measurements using only the $\sigma$-algebra generators?

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, measure-theory

Let $\Omega$ be an open subset of $\mathbb{R}^n$ and let $\mu_1,\, \mu_2: \mathcal{B}(\Omega)\to [0,\,+\infty]$ be two Radon measure on the Borel algebra. Suppose that for every open set $A$ if $\mu_1(A)=0$ then $\mu_2(A)=0$ ( i think with closed sets nothing changes). Is it true that $\mu_2$ is absolutely continuous with respect to $\mu_1$ ?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, it's not true. Let $\mu_1$ be the Lebesgue measure defined on Borel sigma algebra on $\mathbb{R}$, and let $\mu_2$ be the measure defined by $\mu_2(A)=1$ if $0\in A$, otherwise $\mu_2(A)=0$. Both are Radon measures. Well, since there are no non-empty open sets for which $\mu_1(A)=0$ your condition trivially holds. However, $\mu_2$ is obviously not absolutely continuous with respect to $\mu_1$.

Comment: Thanks for your answer!

Comment: Do you think there exists a condition of the type "check the absolute continuity of a suitable subfamily $\mathcal{A}\subset \mathcal{B}(\Omega)$ then the  absolute continuity holds on all $\mathcal{B}(\Omega)$" ? It can be possible ? If yes, what is a good choice for $\mathcal{A}$ ? From the previous question we have that the family of open sets is not a a right choice.

Comment: I think in your case the family of closed sets will work. Since you assume the measures are Radon we know that the the measure of a Borel set is the supremum of measures of its compact subsets. And in $\mathbb{R^n}$ compact sets are closed. So if $\mu_1(A)=0$ then for any compact $K\subseteq A$ we have $\mu_1(K)=0$, but since $K$ is closed this implies $\mu_2(K)=0$. Take the supremum on the compact subsets to get $\mu_2(A)=0$.

Comment: Perfect! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

As per @Mark 's example I believe you your assumption needs to be $\mu_1(A) = 0 \Rightarrow \mu_2(A) =0$ for all $A$ in $\mathcal{B}(\Omega)$.

Comment: This is the definition of absolutely continuous.

Comment: oops...the condition. I meant to give is totally escaping me at this point (has to do with integrals), its relatively simple to prove its equivalent to def'n of AC anyway. Sorry!